# Using FFmpeg to convert all images in a folder to mp4 or avi using a .bat file [Windows]

Tags: image, batch-file, video, ffmpeg, directory

I'm trying to get all .png files in a folder to be converted into a video format in the same directory as the images. Now I can't understand how ffmpeg works, I just want something like this;

```
for /l %%k in (1,1,%images%) do (
    ffmpeg.exe (I need help with the parameters here) 
)
```

This is my very first help request ever and I'm not sure if I supplied enough information for this to be an easy answer. But at least TRYING to help me would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images

Comment: AVI is just a container format (and an aging one). What video format are you wanting to use specifically?

Comment: Any video that the default windows player can play. And thank you for this useful link! I'll see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
set /p framerate=Enter framerate:
for /r %%a in (*.png) do (
    echo file '%%a' >> images.txt
)
ffmpeg.exe -r %framerate% -f concat -i images.txt -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p video.mp4
del /q images.txt
```

Put this batch file AND ffmpeg.exe in the directory of all images
Run the batch file and all images in that the current folder will be converted into an mp4
The batch file will automatically close after it has completed